how to define a nested slices in proto3
I use proto3 to generate api, my proto3 looks like
message CreateSRPolicyDataRequest {
    repeated Path idc_paths = 1;
}
message Path {
    repeated string path = 1;
}

and it turns out
 "idc_paths": [
        {
            "path": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]

but I need
"idc_paths": [
[
                ""
            ]
    ]

how to fix my proto defination?
[packed=true] does not work for string
